# React create two useForm with formState

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm trying to create two `useForm`, but I'm having issues to set the `formState: { erros }`

First userForm

```
const {  
    handleSubmit: handleSubmit1,  
    control: control1,
    setValue: setValue1,
    formState: { erros: errors1 }
} = useForm();
```

Second userForm

```
const {  
    handleSubmit: handleSubmit2,  
    control: control2,
    setValue: setValue2,
    formState: { erros: errors2 }
} = useForm();
```

I received an error saying that `TypeError: errors1 is undefined`. How can I create two errors with different name?

Thanks

Comment: It should be formState: { errors }, not erros.

Comment: @Calvin as I said in the post, I need two useForm, so two errors

Comment: It looks like what you have is correct, you just misspelled errors.

Comment: @Calvin how can I tell React if I want to use errors for the first userForm declaration or errors for the second useForm declaration?

Comment: he meant the key, not the value. The property you're trying to set is misspelled. it's `erros` instead of `errors`

Comment: When you do something like `formState: { errors: errors1 }`, you are [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) `formState` and telling it to assign its `errors` field to a variable called `errors1`. Then, you can use `errors1` to refer to the `errors` of that `formState`.